# iOS - New file type: type description and group title

Tags: ios, custom-data-type

In my iOS app, I declared an "Exported Type Identifier" with a Description as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/defining_file_and_data_types_for_your_app).

So far so good, however, when viewing using **Files.app** with the view option **Group by: Kind**, the group title is the same as the file kind (description).

How to configure or set the group title for a new file type to make it different from file kind?

For example, please see the group title and file kind for a PDF:

- Group title: **PDF Documents**
- File kind: **PDF document**

[image]